# What could prevent a list comprehension with a lowercase name from showing up in Spyder's variable explorer?

Tags: python, spyder

I hope this isn't a trivial question, but I've created a list comprehension with the following code (test code, really) :

```
a = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]
b = [d if d > 5. else None for d in a]
```

... and `b` isn't showing up in Spyder's variable explorer. However, in the ipython console I get

```
In  [1]: b
Out [1]: [None, None, None, None, None, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

What's going on here?

Addendum : when I type `c = None`, `c` doesn't show up in the variable explorer, either.

Comment: If this question is not specific to Python 2.7, you should edit your question to remove that tag. In either case, you should also add the Python tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is specific to Python 2.7. I'll add the Python tag though, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) The problem seems to be with `None` elements as part of your `b` list. If you change your code to

```
a = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]
b = [d if d > 5. else False for d in a]
```

then `b` shows up in the Variable Explorer.

However, this is a bug and we'll fix it for Spyder 3.2 (to be released in a couple of weeks).

Comment: But then if I trace a scatter plot of `b` vs `a`, for instance, the first five points will be zeros, whereas I don't want those five points to exist at all...

Comment: I just offered you a temporary solution to show your b list in the variable explorer, because that was your question about. As I said, this bug will be fixed in Spyder 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

`NoneType` is *not the supported data type* for Spyder's Variable Explorer; [supported data types](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/variableexplorer.html) are

> 1. Pandas DataFrame, TimeSeries and DatetimeIndex objects
> 2. NumPy arrays and matrices
> 3. PIL/Pillow images
> 4. datetime dates
> 5. Integers
> 6. Floats
> 7. Complex numbers
> 8. Lists
> 9. Dictionaries
> 10. Tuples
> 11. Strings

But you may *uncheck* the "Exclude unsupported data types" in Variable Explorer preferences **to show all variables** (including your `b`, of course):

```
Tools -> Preferences -> Variable explorer -> Exclude unsupported data types (uncheck it).
```